# Rails SimpleForm validations don't work with remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a SimpleForm setup with validations that is working well. I would now like to implement AJAX so I don't need to perform page reloads. When I add `:remote => true` to my code the validations no longer work. Is this expected behaviour? Should my SimpleForm validations no longer work when remote is set to true?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @business, :url => {:action => "create", :id => "submit_subscription_signup_form"}, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}, :remote => true do |f| %>

  <% if notification = f.error_notification %>
    <div class="alert alert-error fade in">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
      <%= notification %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :business_name, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>
  <%= f.input :address1, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>
  <%= f.input :city, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>

  <div class="actions" style="text-align: right;"><%= f.submit "Sign Up", :class => 'btn btn-success', :id => "signup_form_submit_button" %></div>
<% end %>
```

And my create action in the controller:

```
def create
@business = Business.new(params[:business])
if @business.save 
  #removed logic for simplicity
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render 'subscriptions/_logged_in' }
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'index' }
      format.js { render 'subscriptions/_signup' }
   end
end
end
```

And seeing as I want the submit to fail and show validations, then my _signup.js.erb partial will be called. The main view contains a number of forms that are either shown or hidden through jQuery. So the _signup.js.erb contains:

```
$('#login_form').hide()
$('#logged_in_form').hide()
$('#signup_form').show()
```

Comment: Well, how does the AJAX response look like?

Comment: I'm following Railscast episode 136 revised. In it Ryan suggests to check the Network tab of the browser to see if an AJAX request was made. Is this how I would check the AJAX response?

Comment: No, what I meant is how is your js view structured, something like create.js.erb

Comment: I updated my question to include the controller action and the js partial.

Comment: 1. you are calling your partials with `_`, I am not sure, but I think you can call them without that. And 2. you are not showing validations in `.js.erb`, I would expect to see something like: `@user.errors.each`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am now able to access the errors in the .js.erb file. Now that I have my errors, how do I add them to the same error block as seen in my code in my original question: `<% if notification = f.error_notification %>` ? It would be nice if I could have the same styling applied whilst keeping it DRY.